# Checking if each value in large vector is in other large vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of about 800K IDs, and I want to check if it's part of one of two other large vectors, "active" and "cancelled", each with about 1 million records. How can I do this? Obviously looping through 800K Ids and doing an %in% check for both "active" and "cancelled" vectors would take forever...is there a quicker way?

My goal is to have list for each of the 800K IDs if they are active or cancelled, and get somethign like the following:

```
ID    Active    Cancelled
123     1           0
124     1           0
...
```

Comment: We can try `+(df1$Active %in% vec1)`  If these are character vectors, you can use `%chin%` from `data.table`

Comment: You mentioned that you are looping for each ID separately.  It is not clear why that is necessary.  If you can provide a small reproducible example with expected output, it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with vectors you should give the `intersect` function a shot ... which is basically just a wrapped `%in%` but nevertheless ...